# React App renders blank page on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, build, github-pages

I'm new to React and after deployment, github page is blank, with multiple 404 errors in console

I changed website url template in package.json, but still nothing

Here's my repo: https://github.com/Sanideth/Social-Media-Dashboard-with-Theme-Switcher-With-React

Any help would be much appreciated!

P.S Initial deployment had an error, due to file name length, but I found a solution via git config script and it worked and deployment was successfull!

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to commit the built version of the app to the repo rather than just the source code. As far as I know github pages won't run the build process for you.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I  noticed that default .gitignore  which create-react-app generates includes build/ folder, should I delete that line and commit/push again?

Comment: does the build folder contain a complete app? you may want to have a repo for the source code and a separate repo for the built app which powers the github page, as i think you may want the github page root to be the build folder. I haven't actually done this before though so I'm guessing

Comment: Well, here's the link of my other project, which I did couple of days ago, I did the same thing with this and it got deployed without any problem

Comment: In the settings for the repository, have you set the branch to `gh-pages` for the GitHub Pages section?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Sorry then I'm out of ideas, it looks like you've done everything right to me

Comment: Thanks for your efforr!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to add base href to head tag.

The link should be

```
https://<github-user-name>.github.io>/<github-repo-name>
```

Sample

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Application</title>
  <base href="https://Sanidethgithub.github.io/Social-Media-Dashboard-with-Theme-Switcher-With-React/">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Hmm previous project  didn't need that. I'll try it though